# PCB electroplating then etching

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, diy, through-hole, etching

How can I protect the through holes copper which is electroplated from being etched away by the ferric chloride?  Is there a resistive solution or it`s just the conductive ink.

Comment: @user253751  In industrial PCB production, there's a plating step after drilling but before etching.  That's when the insides of vias are plated.  During etching, the vias are protected by photoresist.

Comment: @NickAlexeev i use toner transfer method not photoresist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same photoresist that keep the copper from being etched away should generally keep the hole plating from being etched away.  If not, they can be painted explicitly.

Comment: I use toner transfer not photoresist , and how to expose these tiny holes to ultraviolet light?

Comment: if they use a positive photoresist they don't need to expose the holes.  you could use wax, or a wax-based paint to protect the vias.

Comment: @AhmedEmad then toner is taking the place of photoresist in your process